# how to retrive the country code ios example

Tags: ios, country-codes, mobile-country-code

I want to display the country code in a uitextfield. 
Is there some source code example on iOS about this?
I did some search, but i can t find anything concrete.
I need a start point.

Comment: Look at `NSLocale` assuming you mean codes likes US, DE, ES, CA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];`

That will give you the country/language code (assuming that's what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

This will give just the country code. E.g. `US`, `AU`, etc.

```
NSString *countryCode = [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode] uppercaseString];
```

Comment: i see. thank you. What is the best way to retrive the prefix for each cuontry code? E.G US = 001 OR +1.